# How to avoid word wrap in jQuery UI menu

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, menu, submenu

I have created a fiddle to show a problem I'm having: http://jsfiddle.net/A5HyU/2/

On that fiddle, click on the button on the right, then go to the menu item `Segnalibri`, you'll notice that the submenu that opens has the second element in which the word `Condiviso` is somehow wrapped, but I would need the submenu to be sufficiently large to hold the whole word.

Is a problem of my setup or in the library itself?

To solve it I have tried two different solutions, the first is css based:

```
.jqSubMenu > li > a {
  min-width: [XXX]px
}
```

This works, but requires me to pick a value which must be correct for every possible sub-menu I set up.

The second is js based:

```
$('.jqSubMenu').each(function() {
    var l = 0;

    $('> li > a', this).each(function() {
        l = Math.max(l, $(this).text().trim().length);
    }).css('min-width', (l * 8) + 'px');
});
```

This seems to work too, but slows down submenu initialization.

I also tried to change my surrounding css modifications, but none seem to affect the submenu layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

To mentioned elements and see where does that get you.

Comment: Sadly this only works half-way, now the text overlaps the right icon, see http://jsfiddle.net/A5HyU/3/